# Searching MySql database for joined strings in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database that has a elements column. Inside the elements, there are various items i.e Ca, O, H e.t.c.

The input form will have inputs like CaO or HO.

1. I want to be able to search the database and match those two items first before i can go ahead and use the items.
2. Matched inputs should come up as items i.e Ca, O, H.

What is the best way to search the database  for joined strings like those(CaO or HO ) where they exist individually in database.

I have tried exploding it but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What do you mean with `match those two items first`? Can you provide sample input data and your expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could "reverse" `LIKE` like:

```
WHERE 'CaO' LIKE CONCAT('%', table.element, '%')
```

obviously `'CaO'` comes from PHP.

Although I'm not sure if this will give the expected result.

Comment: Thanks, something along those lines. I was brainstorming and now i will try a variation of that.